# Is wget a default Windows 10 command in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, wget

I need know if wget is a default command in Windows 10, because I want to run a .bat file in some customer's computers to run a script. I would prefer not to install wget separately, just use it.

So, is it available by default in Windows 10?

Comment: Wget is an Powershell alias for Invoke-WebRequest.